# Is this the right usage of ng-container?

Tags: angular, angular6, angular8

I have a `Product` component with a child `ShareButton` component:

```
<app-product>
   <app-share-button (click)="click($event)"></app-share-button>
</app-product>
```

When I click the `ShareButton`, it returns data to the parent component via: `click($event`)`:

```
public click($event) {
     this.typeAction = $event.type;
}
```

Is it a good idea to use `ng-container` in the parent component like this:

```
<app-product>
   <app-share-button (click)="click($event)"></app-share-button>
   <ng-container [ngIf]="typeAction === 'new'">
        <app-new [type]="1"></app-new>
        <app-new [type]="2"></app-new>
   </ng-container>

    <ng-container [ngIf]="typeAction === 'new'">
         <app-exist [type]="1"></app-exist>
         <app-exist [type]="2"></app-exist>
     </ng-container>
</app-product>
```

Should this be simplified or is this a valid use case for `ng-container`?

Comment: You can use ng-container where ever you techically need a for e.g div element to apply some logic but you dont want to create a real dom element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as it's serving a purpose, there's not really an incorrect usage of `ng-container`. All it does is provide an element in the HTML that you can do angular stuff to but doesn't actually get rendered to the page.

That being said, if you're goal is to have the `app-new` elements and the `app-exist` elements be siblings, this is absolutely the right usage.

But let me point out, you would probably be better off using the shorthand notation of [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) of `*ngIf="condition"`. The `*` indicates that it is a [structural directive](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives) that lets angular know to use a template for the inner elements.

That brings up the most common use case of `ng-container`. Since structural directives can change what elements are within it, you can only have one of these per element. So, when you need to have multiple structural directives, you can nest them with `ng-container`s.